# How to keep a tag clickable inside a container that is show on focus and hidden on mouse out

Tags: jquery, html, css

Can someone help me please, 
well i have a search button which  has a container that must be show on focus and to be hidden on mouseout... i have done it already but the `a` tag  on that container  are not clickable.

How can i make them to be click.

thanks!

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".search-field").focus(function() {
    $(".search-resoult").css({
      "display": "block",
      "opacity": "1",
      "width": "410px",
      " pointer-events"
      "auto"
    });
  });
  $(".search-field").blur(function() {
    $(".search-resoult").css({
      "opacity": "0",
      "width": "0"
    });
  });


});
```

```css
.search {
  float: right;
  margin: 0 20px;
}
.search-field {
  height: 55px;
  background-color: transparent;
  background-image: url(../img/logo/search.png);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: 20px 20px;
  background-position: 5px center;
  position: relative;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  border-bottom: 1px solid transparent;
  padding: 0 0 0 30px;
  -webkit-transition: width 400ms ease, background 400ms ease;
  transition: width 400ms ease, background 400ms ease;
  margin-top: -11px;
}
.search-field {
  width: 0;
}
.search-field:hover {
  border: none;
  background-color: inherit;
  border-bottom: 1px solid transparent;
}
.search-field:focus {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #FF4343;
  cursor: text;
  outline: 0;
  width: 380px;
  padding: 0 0 0 30px;
  pointer-events: auto;
}
.input[type="search"] {
  -webkit-appearance: textfield;
}
.search-resoult {
  height: auto;
  position: fixed;
  width: 0;
  opacity: 0;
  top: 60px;
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
  z-index: 999;
  border: 1px solid #ced8e1;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 8px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 8px;
  -webkit-transition: width 400ms ease, background 400ms ease;
  transition: width 400ms ease, background 400ms ease;
}
.search-resoult-content {
  width: 330px;
  position: relative;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 20px 0px;
}
.search-resoult-content ul {
  text-align: justify;
}
.search-resoult-content ul li {
  display: inline-block;
  list-style: none;
  margin: 13px 2px;
}
.search-resoult-content ul li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  border-radius: 5px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
  color: #101010;
  font-family: 'gothamthinregular';
  font-weight: 900;
  font-size: 1.01rem;
  letter-spacing: 0.03rem;
  border: 1px solid #B0B1B3;
  padding: 10px 15px;
  transition: border-color .3s, color .3s;
}
.search-resoult-content ul li a:hover {
  border-color: #FF4343;
  color: #FF4343;
}
.search-resoult-content ul li a:focus {
  border-color: #FF4343;
  color: #FF4343;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="search">
  <form action="#" autocomplete="on" class="search-form" method="get">
    <input class="search-field" placeholder="Kerko …" title="Kerko:" id="search_field" type="search" autocomplete="off">
  </form>
  <div class="search-resoult" style="display: block; opacity: 0; width: 0px;">
    <div class="search-resoult-content">
      <ul>
        <li><a href="test.html">Test1</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="test2.html">Test2</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="test3.html">Test3</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="test4.html">Test4</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="search-bottom">
      <div class="search-bottom-content">
        <a href="#">Lexo me shume</a>
      </div>
      <!-- end the search bottom content -->
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: please post in your question the code that you have so far, and show us what you have tried in order to make it work

Comment: hey i have a search the  almost similar with flipboard, this is the idea... but my a tag there are not clickable

Comment: correct me if im wrong, but you are not having issues with flipboard, you are having issues with the code that you have written yourself. therefore we need to see that code if you want us to help you. please paste the code in your question.

Comment: In you snippet it is clickable. Do you have some jquery or js code for this?

Comment: $(".search-resoult").css({ "display": "block", "opacity": "1","width":"410px", " pointer-events""auto" }); error here make it pointer-events""auto" like pointer-events":"auto"

Comment: hey i'm sorry guys i don't know to use well stackoverflow :D  that's why i make stupid things :D  @Banana

Comment: @Farhan i was playing with the code but it's not the problem here...

Comment: @GertaXhepi thats alright, we will fix your question whenever it needs editting. on topic: in the snippet the textbox doesnt appear at all, is that supposed to happen or is it part of the problem?

Comment: On  my localhost i am able to click link and page redirect to that clicked link

Comment: @Banana please wait i will do a copy on codepen and i will show u it... :D

Comment: As it stands your links should be clickable: https://jsfiddle.net/xm02k03h/.  Are the styles for search  bottom meaning it covers the links?  Also, if you inspect element on the links, does it actually inspect the link or something covering it?

Comment: so if u take a look here when u click on the link inside the search-resoult the link can not be clicked...  http://codepen.io/xhepigerta/pen/jWzPpJ

Comment: i am sure you are testing this on chrome, as this is working on FF. Answer i gave is working in FF not in chrome

Comment: yes i'm working on chrome...

Comment: but i want  that this to work there

Comment: @GertaXhepi your code works fine in chrome as well. the issue is with codepen because its sandbox window probably does not allow redirection to external links. try running the code from an html file on your desktop and it should work

Comment: No the problem is to the method blur in jquery...., but i will try to solve that :D